# Show that inner measure is the same as outer measure on Lebesgue measurable sets.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

I am trying to answer **part (a)** problem from Axler's book, Measure, Integration and Real Analysis (seen below). I think I'm almost there but I'm stuck on a certain case.

[image: Problem]

We also have the following equivalences from a theorem in the book:

[image: Equivalences]

Let $A$ be a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
If we let Inn denote the inner measure function,
it's easy to see from the definitions that Inn$(A)\leq|A|$.

If $A$ is bounded and $|A|<\infty$,

then $\exists$ a closed, bounded set $F$ s.t. $F\subset A$ and $|F|<\infty$ and $|A\setminus F|<\epsilon$ (using equivalence (b) from above).

$\implies |A|<|F|+\epsilon$ (using $|A\setminus F|=|A|-|F|$).

$\implies |A|\leq$ Inn$(F)+\epsilon$.

$\implies |A|\leq$ Inn$(F)$.

**The issue now is what to do if ${\mathbf A}$ is unbounded or ${\mathbf |A|=\infty}$** (possibly both at the same time). We can't use $|A\setminus F|=|A|-|F|$ like before or say that $F$ is bounded like before.

Below I include Axler's definition of outer measure, in case it is not standard:

[image: length of interval]
[image: outer measure]

Comment: A general trick is to consider $A_n=A\cap[-n,n]$ which is bounded. Then $|A_n|=\text{Inn}(A_n)\le\text{Inn}(A)$, so taking $n\to\infty$ gives $|A|\le\text{Inn}(A)$.